# reverse an input string in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I am trying to reverse the string in assembly but its not working its not reading the character of string ! 
please help out , it is printing only $$$$$ against any character. what am i trying to write !

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
input db 10 dup ('$')
output db 10 dup('$')

.code
main proc

mov ax , @data
mov ds , ax 
mov bx , offset input
mov cx , 0

l1:
    mov ah , 1
    int 21h
    mov [bx] , al
    inc bx 
    inc cx
    cmp al , 13
    jne l1

    mov dx , offset input
    mov ah , 9 
    int 21h

    mov si , cx

    ou:
    mov dl , [bx+si]
    mov ah , 2
    int 21h
    dec bx
    dec cx 
    cmp cx   , 1
    jne ou


mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be more appropriate to reverse the string and then print it, instead of printing each character in reverse?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Probably the OP wants to print first in order to verify his efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you forgot to setup BX in the reverse-display loop. Try this code:

```
mov si , cx
mov bx, offset input
ou:
mov dl , [bx+si-1]
mov ah , 2
int 21h
dec si
jnz ou
```

You can easily change this routine so that it stores the reverse string in the buffer pointed at by *output*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very simple routine to do the job :

```
strrev:
  mov al, [si]
  mov [di], al
  dec si
  inc di
  loop strrev
  ret
```

It accepts the number of characters inside the string in `cx`, the address of the last character of the input string in `si`, and the address of the buffer for the new string in `di`. Call it, and then use `Int 21/AH=09h` to display the reversed string. Terminating the output string with `$` is left to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
data segment
    string1 db 'CBITA'
    length equ ($-string1)

    string2 db ?
data ends
code segment 
    assume cs:code ds:data es:data
    start:
       mov ax,data
       mov ds,ax   
       lea si,string1
       lea di,string2


       mov cx,length  

       add si,cx


       add si,-1    
    cld


 strrev:
  mov al, [si]
  mov [di], al
  dec si
  inc di  
  dec cx
  jnz strrev


            hlt   

            code ends
            end start
```

Comment: `length` is a constant, you could just `mov si, length-1 + offset string1` instead of using 4 instructions.  (You don't need `cx`, your loop condition could be `cmp si, offset string1` / `jne`.